# Is there a Flutter Treegrid widget or Treetable widget available as a package in year 2024?

Tags: flutter, widget

I saw four years ago, back in year 2020, there was an answer referring to 2 packages. From my perspective, one of the packages was no longer supported, but was touted as being "modifiable". The other did not actually have the capability. One was expected to create the capability using one of these packages as a foundation point.

I'm a complete noob to Flutter coming from the Python world where almost everything one can imagine is available with running examples. Flutter seems a great alternative, but when needing the above mentioned widget, I can't find a running example anywhere. Maybe I'm not looking in the right places. Maybe I am, but don't know what the package might be called.

To develop quickly (like Python) one must have working widgets; not being expected to create one that may be common; especially if new to the Flutter world.

Does anyone know of the existence of a Treegrid or Treetable widget for Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

YAYYY!!!!! I found a package that does 99% of everything I want!
It's called flutter_expandable_table. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_expandable_table/example

I knew there had to be something after 4 years time since Flutter is so wonderful.

Hope this helps everyone looking for the same functionality!

Answer (score -1):

Flutter is indeed a great alternative of Python since the developer of Flutter is Google itself which makes it easy for developing android based applications. The packages which you are searching for might be outdated but can work like a piece of cake it is just a matter of testing out the relevant dependencies.

Make sure to check every dependency/plugin from https://pub.dev/ and test it out for the best match. You can also use flutter default data_table for the same. The data_table widget in the Flutter SDK provides a basic tabular layout, but it doesn't support hierarchical structures out of the box. However, you might be able to customize it to create a tree-like structure.

Comment: You're suggesting, as far as a TreeGrid widget is concerned, there is absolutely nothing that's been developed in 4 years time?? If so, that doesn't bode well for increasing popularity of Flutter. Can anyone out there help me with this problem??